# TP-Link TG-3468 Ethernet pci card not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, ethernet, tp-link

Hi i bought a new pci ethernet card as my motherboard ethernet would constantly crash at random times causing the computer to continue to run and have no networking abilities.

The new card is recognized + the driver (r8169) is already being used by the previous motherboard ethernet

lspci output (new card is 05:00.0):

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

lsmod also has r8169 listed.

when the ethernet is plugged into the new card the light blinks green so power is running through.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you could try to find a Bios setting that disable the onboard NIC.
If not available, you can disable the system pci device.

Disable a system pci device by the `remove` command. A file called `remove` is located in the system pci ressource directory. When it contains 1, the device is disabled

`sudo echo 1 > '/sys/dev/pcixxxx:xx/xxxx:xx:xx:x/remove'`

```
# 1 - Find the PCI device ID
$ lspci | grep -i eth
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
# To find which one have to be disabled, Check 'lshw -C network'
# Want to remove pci 06:00.0

# 2 - Find the system device folder
$ sudo find /sys *06:00.0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:06:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xxxx/0000:06:00.0
# the system device dir is /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:06:00.0

# 3 - Remove the pci device : write '1' to the 'remove' file
$ sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:06\:00.0/remove

# If needed : Update Udev
$ sudo udevadm trigger /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/
```

Comment: both ethernet cards are missing in /sys/devices/ so both 05:00.0 and 06:00.0 are missing but they exist in /sys/bus/pci/devices/. so i tried to apply the same method to the remove file in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/remove but it gives permission denied even with sudo. just to note, the find command didnt find either pci card folders even though they exist in the one i mentioned